# yaml::yaml.load_file cannot open file

Tags: r

I am trying to load a file in R using yaml::yaml.load_file, but am getting the error

```
cannot open file 'home/aaaa/bbbbb/ccc/dddd.yml': No such file or directory
```

even though the file exists at the location. Can you please tell the reason behind this error

Comment: If the file path is supposed to be absolute, it's missing a `/` at the beginning. What does `file.exists('home/aaaa/bbbbb/ccc/dddd.yml')` tell you?